# how to set capabilities (setcap) on perf

Tags: 20.04, setcap

So I asked the same question on Unix and Linux Stack Exchange, but I haven't received any answers. I'd like to use the perf utility. I was following instructions to set up a privileged group of users who are permitted to execute performance monitoring and observability without limits (as instructed here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html). I added the group and limited access to users not in the group. I started having problems when assigning capabilities to the perf tool:

```
setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf
```

I'd like to use the perf utility. I was following instructions to set up a privileged group of users who are permitted to execute performance monitoring and observability without limits (as instructed here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html). I added the group and limited access to users not in the group. I started having problems when assigning capabilities to the perf tool:

setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf

I get an invalid arguments error saying

```
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] [-n <rootid>] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

But running `stats perf` gives me this

```
  File: ./perf
  Size: 1622        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10307h/66311d   Inode: 35260925    Links: 1
Access: (0750/-rwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/perf_users)
Access: 2021-12-03 13:08:48.923220351 +0100
Modify: 2021-11-05 17:02:56.000000000 +0100
Change: 2021-12-03 12:31:49.451991980 +0100
 Birth: -
```

which says the file is a regular file. What could be the problem? How can I set the capabilities for the Perf tool?

Comment: Are you running the setcap command from the perf command's containing directory (/usr/bin or /bin)?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the setcap command from /usr/bin.